# The age and weight of the person is/are known?

Tags: verbs, plural-forms, singular

I am not sure whether to use singular or plural forms of the verb in the following example sentence:

> The age and weight of the person is/are known.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 3):

The subject here is "age and weight", so a plural verb is correct. Whenever you have a compound subject joined by "*and*", you should use a plural verb.

Here, "the person" is the object of the *of* clause. It is not the subject of the sentence.

> The **age and weight** [of the person] **are** known.

Consider different versions of your sentence, which make the verb choice more obvious:

> The person's age and weight are known.
>
> His age and weight are known.

Answer (score 1):

Here the verb should be plural i.e. "ARE". It's a case of subject verb agreement. Here the subject is plural( "age and weight" together makes up the subject) so the verb used should also be plural.